# keeps on giving error on the line compareResult = v.compareTo(t.getData()). iterative insert method for BST

Tags: java

```
public void insert(int v) {
    Node t = root;
    int compareResult;
    compareResult = 0;
    if ((t.getData()).equals(v)) return;
    if (t == null) {
        Node n = new Node<>(v, t, null, null);
    } else
        while (t != null) {

            compareResult = v.compareTo(t.getData());
            if (compareResult > 0) {
                if (t.getRight() != null) {
                    t = t.getRight();
                } else {
                    Node n = t.getRight();
                    break;
                }
            }

            else {
                compareResult = v.compareTo(t.getData());
                if (compareResult < 0) {
                    if (t.getLeft() != null) {
                        t = t.getLeft();
                    } else {
                        Node n = t.getLeft();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: you need to be more specific

Comment: You need to tell us what the error you're getting is.

Answer (score 1):

v is a primitive int. You can't call methods on primitive types in Java.

You can however replace `v.compareTo(t.getData())` with `Integer.compare(v, t.getData())`